# specify minimum and maximum length of a string using java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following complex regex pattern :

```
(((([0-9])?[A-Z]{1,})(([A-Z0-9./+]+){0,}-){1,})[A-Z0-9./+]+\=*)
```

which matches the following strings.

```
GCD-800F-RM-19
RCS8XX-256U512D=
CDE-HY14-2RJ11++
```

I need to set a minimum and maximum length for this pattern now, as I don't want a match for the following words :
`IP-IP` , `CD-X` etc.

How can I set the minimum length as 5 and max length as 18 for the above pattern?

Please find the link for online editor here:
https://regex101.com/r/GblzUj/5

Comment: Why must this be done with a regex? Why not simply check the string length?

Comment: Also, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/GblzUj/6)

Comment: Thanks for the quick help ..I have tried specifying the length as  {5,18} but it is a complex pattern, this method is not working .. Do we have any other method for specifying the length ?